# Pandas plot line graph with both error bars and markers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to use `pandas.plot` to plot a line chart that should contain both markers and error bars. But for some reason markers are not shown if I specify `yerr` values.

These are data frames:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [45.0, 44.26608641544399, 43.08429058188399, 42.06431734681251, 40.71632532212173, 39.93952782686818],
'Infubinol': [45.0, 47.062001033088, 49.40390857087143, 51.29639655633334, 53.19769093422999, 55.71525236228889],
'Ketapril': [45.0, 47.38917452114348, 49.582268974622714, 52.39997374321578, 54.92093473734737, 57.678981717731574],
'Placebo': [45.0, 47.125589188437495, 49.42332947868749, 51.35974169802999, 54.36441702681052, 57.48257374394706]})
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

errors = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [0.0, 0.44859285020103756, 0.7026843745238932, 0.8386172472985688, 0.9097306924832056, 0.8816421535181787],
'Infubinol': [0.0, 0.23510230430767506, 0.2823459146215716, 0.35770500497539054, 0.4762095134790833, 0.5503145721542003],
'Ketapril': [0.0, 0.26481852016728674, 0.35742125637213723, 0.5802679659678779, 0.7264838239834724, 0.7554127528910378],
'Placebo': [0.0, 0.21809078325219497, 0.40206380730509245, 0.6144614435805993, 0.8396091719248746, 1.0348719877946384]})
errors.set_index('Time', inplace=True)
```

Here is what happens when I plot without errors:

```
df.plot(figsize=(12,8), 
        style=['^-', 'o--', 'x-.', 'D-'], 
        markersize=14)
```

[image]

And this one is with error bars:

```
df.plot(figsize=(12, 8), 
        style=['^-', 'o--', 'x-.', 'D-'], 
        yerr=errors,
        markersize=14)
```

[image]

So how can I plot them both?

**UPD**: sample data as data frames

**Environment:** OS - Win10 x64, pandas 0.23, matplotlib 2.2.2

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: You might also want to include your environment (matplotlib, pandas version, backend, OS) in your question.

Comment: Added some sample data and environment details

Comment: I don't understand your sample data. Your code seems to have all data in one dataframe df (which would be the logical choice), but your sample data are in two dataframes. It is also not clear, why your code produces with this sample dataframe your output. Pandas would with your code plot columns, which in your case would be Time and Value. I think you have to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'll take my time tomorrow to prepare a proper dataset for you, sorry about that

Comment: @Mr.T I've added sample data

Comment: I've actually ended up plotting every series with separate plt.errorbar command - this gives the same kind of chart but with both markers and errorbars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I can confirm that this happens also in Ubuntu 18.04, pandas 0.23.4, matplotlib 2.2.3 with TkAgg backend. I am not sure, if this is a bug or a feature, but you can emulate the expected behavior:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#create your sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [45.0, 44.26608641544399, 43.08429058188399, 42.06431734681251, 40.71632532212173, 39.93952782686818],
'Infubinol': [45.0, 47.062001033088, 49.40390857087143, 51.29639655633334, 53.19769093422999, 55.71525236228889],
'Ketapril': [45.0, 47.38917452114348, 49.582268974622714, 52.39997374321578, 54.92093473734737, 57.678981717731574],
'Placebo': [45.0, 47.125589188437495, 49.42332947868749, 51.35974169802999, 54.36441702681052, 57.48257374394706]})
df.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

errors = pd.DataFrame({
'Time': [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
'Capomulin': [0.0, 0.44859285020103756, 0.7026843745238932, 0.8386172472985688, 0.9097306924832056, 0.8816421535181787],
'Infubinol': [0.0, 0.23510230430767506, 0.2823459146215716, 0.35770500497539054, 0.4762095134790833, 0.5503145721542003],
'Ketapril': [0.0, 0.26481852016728674, 0.35742125637213723, 0.5802679659678779, 0.7264838239834724, 0.7554127528910378],
'Placebo': [0.0, 0.21809078325219497, 0.40206380730509245, 0.6144614435805993, 0.8396091719248746, 1.0348719877946384]})
errors.set_index('Time', inplace=True)

#plot error bars
ax = df.plot(figsize=(12,8), yerr = errors, legend = False)
#reset color cycle so that the marker colors match
ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
#plot the markers
df.plot(figsize=(12,8), style=['^-', 'o--', 'x-.', 'D-'], markersize=14, ax = ax)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]