# Pandas line plot with no lines and error bars (from groupby with cut)

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Attempting to add error bars to a pandas line plot seems to negate previous information provided as arguments. In particular, it seems to ignore the choice to not include the lines. What I'm trying to do is create a line plot without any lines, but including the error bars. See MWE below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

dates = np.array([dt(2012, 9, 27, 8, 52, 21),
       dt(2012, 10, 6, 5, 4, 15),
       dt(2012, 10, 7, 4, 53, 4),
       dt(2012, 10, 9, 7, 21, 18),
       dt(2012, 10, 10, 5, 4, 8),
       dt(2012, 10, 11, 4, 58, 43),
       dt(2012, 10, 12, 11, 15, 25),
       dt(2012, 10, 13, 10, 45, 23),
       dt(2012, 10, 20, 6, 0, 25),
       dt(2012, 10, 22, 7, 41, 38)])

values = np.array([5.61006523, 5.39632183, 5.49317193, 5.42327983, 5.4623386, 
                   5.42444747, 5.60362929, 5.57041331, 5.34893575, 5.48222005])

date_bins = np.array([dt(2012, 9, 29, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 10, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 14, 14),
                      dt(2012, 10, 23, 14)])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates, 'value': values})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bin_dates':date_bins})

lookup = df1.groupby(pd.cut(df1['date'], df2['bin_dates'])).agg({'value':['mean','std']})
lookup.columns = ['mean_val','std_val']

lookup[['mean_val']].plot(kind='line',style='o',yerr=lookup[['std_val']].values.T)
```

Result with error bars (ignore the terrible x-axis labeling):
[image: with error bars]

Result without error bars:
[image: without error bars]

Does anyone know a workaround for this? The closest I've come across is a workaround that keeps the lines in place [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52035184/pandas-plot-line-graph-with-both-error-bars-and-markers). Additionally, it's gone unanswered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103273/pandas-plot-with-error-bars-but-without-lines). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you only want to use pandas? Or matplotlib will work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off of Sheldore's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56588917/5001432), we can add the data points back in on top by cycling back through the colors, and replotting the data without the error bars.

```
ax = lookup[['mean_val']].plot(kind='line',style='o',yerr=lookup[['std_val']].values.T,legend=False)
ax.lines[0].remove()
ax.set_prop_cycle(None)
lookup[['mean_val']].plot(kind='line',style='o',ax=ax)
```

Resulting in:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Without resorting to `matplotlib`, the workaround solution that comes to my mind is to remove the line object using the axis instance `ax` returned from the `df.plot()`

```
ax = lookup[['mean_val']].plot(kind='line', style='o', yerr=lookup[['std_val']].values.T)
ax.lines[0].remove()
```

[image]